# Which GPIOs are OUTPUT and HIGH at startup?

Tags: rpi.gpio

I need such a GPIO for an LED that must be on as soon as possible after the PI is started up.

I've played with the device trees but documentation on those is sparse (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no pins that are set as outputs driven high for the simple reason that it is not a good practice; of course it is still possible to leave something wired up the wrong way, turn it on, and short something out, but the chances of that happening are much *less* if there are not an arbitrary number of general input/output pins set by default as +.

> I've played with the device trees but documentation on those is sparse (in my opinion).

It sounds in fact then like you have a different question than what you actually asked -- you would like to know *how* to turn an LED on ASAP.

If so, please do so in a new, separate question.  Likewise if you have a more specific question about device tree overlays.